# SSL Handshake Failing

Tags: tls

Hi I have a server running on AWS which has SSL (both server and client authentication). After the server runs for approximately over 10 hours the clients are unable to connect and get a SSLHandshakeException. The time on the server is UTC and the client timezone is whatever country they are in since it is a mobile app. I was wondering if this is something to do with a discrepancy in time between the client and the server? If I restart the server (its a Node.js script) it seems to work fine, for another 10 hours or so but then it fails requiring another restart? Any ideas, most of the devices at the moment are in Australia using AEST (GMT + 10)

Comment: Time zones aren't the problem.

Comment: @ Amateur NetMan no I didn't think so, I was thinking it might have something to do with clock synchronisation? Any Ideas?

Comment: Maybe, Java is emulated after all. But Node.js works for everyone else, so what else could be the problem? "SSLHandshakeException" could be many errors, the cert not being trusted, the encryption not being agreed upon, etc. What is confusing is that it suddenly happens at 10 hrs. Perhaps more testing is needed.

Comment: 10 hours was a rough guess, but if a restart the server and then go to bed, and then wake up it wont connect. This has happened twice in a row. It works for a certain amount of time and then suddenly stops working, so it seems to have something to do with time, otherwise if it was misconfiguration then it shouldnt work at all. Going to try regen the certificates on a machine with UTC time to see if that helps

Comment: Sounds good. Maybe you can setup a connection testing loop that logs times when it fails. Then monitor the server for any changes, etc. around that time.

Comment: Will do. If that fails I have no idea what is wrong ...

Comment: OK it did not work, I am getting the following error when trying to connect to the server with OpenSSL:CONNECTED(00000003)
140201993528992:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:sslhandshake failure:s23_lib.c:177: as well as this line: Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported. Keep in mind that it does work for a decent period of time before failing so it doesnt seem like a certificate error

Comment: Figured it out it was a really stupid error, I was using socket.end() not socket.destroy() in nodejs apparently socket.end() was half closing the socket which was causing handshake problems after a while. I changed to socket.destroy() and it works like a charm